# Alternatives to eval() for multiple nested objects

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm trying to create a generic i18n solution for a HTML app I'm working in. I'm looking for alternatives to use eval() to call deeply nested Javascript objects:

Suppose the following HTML example:

```
<div id="page1">
  <h1 data-i18n="html.pageOne.pageTitle"></h1>
</div>
```

and it's companion Javascript (using jQuery):

```
var i18n;

i18n = {
  html: {
     pageOne: {
       pageTitle: 'Lorem Ipsum!'
     }
  }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-18n]').each(function () {
    var q;

    q = eval('i18n.' + $(this).attr('data-i18n'));
    if (q) {
      $(this).text(q);
    }
  });
});
```

Any advices on how to access the "pageTitle" property inside the i18n object without using eval()? I need to keep the object's structure, so changing its layout to a "flat" solution is not feasible.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use bracket syntax, as others have hinted at. But, you'll need to split and iterate at `.`:

```
function lookup(obj, path) {
    var keys = path.split('.'),
        result = obj;

    for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
        result = result[keys[i]];

        // exit early if `null` or `undefined`
        if (result == null)
            return result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then:

```
q = lookup(i18n, $(this).attr('data-i18n'));
if (q) {
  $(this).text(q);
}
```

Comment: Neat solution. I was hoping there was a different way (maybe language-provided, or using jQuery) to do this.

Answer (score 4):

The dot syntax (`object.field`) is really just syntactic sugar for `object['field']`. If you find yourself writing `eval('object.'+field)`, you should simply write `object['field']` instead. In your example above, you probably want: `i18n[$(this).attr('data-i18n')]`.

Since you're encoding your attribute in a way that has dots in it, try splitting it by the dots, and iterating over the fields. For example (this can probably be improved):

```
var fields = $(this).attr('i18n').split('.');
fieldCount = fields.length;
fieldIdx = 0;
var cur = i18n;
while(cur != undefined && fieldIdx > fieldCount) {
    cur = cur[fields[fieldIdx++]];
}
```

You'll want to do additional checking to make sure all of the fields were handled, nulls weren't encountered, etc.

Comment: I agree brackets are better than `eval`, but won't work in this case as is -- `{"html.pageOne.pageTitle": ...}` vs. `{html: {pageOne: {pagetitle: ...}}}`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Updated answer with a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string on the periods and traverse the object:

```
var q = i18n;
$.each($(this).attr('data-i18n').split('.'), function(index, key){
  if (q) q = q[key];
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GsVsr/