# Alternative to eval() in javascript for a deep function

Tags: javascript, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternatives to eval() for multiple nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893983/alternatives-to-eval-for-multiple-nested-objects)

I'm trying to find an alternative to `eval()`. I use it to call a function from a string.

I'm aware of `window["myFunction"](args)` but my functions are inside another objects.

It can be for example `"myObject.anotherOne.myFunction"` or `"myObject.myFunction"` or any kind of deep.

Does someone have an idea please?

Comment: Not really sure what you are looking for here... What does `eval()` do wrong? What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. the linked duplicate is about object value, I need to call a function. Indeed it gives me ideas to achive my goal but i'm not done yet

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a function name and using eval just pass the function directly.

```
var toCall = function () { 
  console.log("toCall was called");
};

// Call via eval
var evalSample = function (theName) { 
  ...
  eval(theName);
}
evalSample('toCall');

// Call via callback
var funcSample = function (theFunc) {
  ...
  theFunc();
};
funcSample(toCall);
```

Comment: passing a function name isn't an option in my case. That's all I have.