# How to update a var in nested objects

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object and I want to set a variable deep nested inside this object, but the var does not yet exist. What's the best way to do this? If I for example have a string that shows where the variable to be updated should be, like below.

```
var myObject = {};
var location = "myObject.test.myVar";
var value = "My value!";
setValue(location, value, myObject);
```

I want this to result in:

```
myObject = {
    test: {
        myVar: "My value!"
    }
};
```

And location can be much deeper than that.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!
Andreas

Comment: Are you sure about the location? You're using `myObject` both in the location and in `setValue`.

Comment: Take a look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893983/alternatives-to-eval-for-multiple-nested-objects)

Answer (score 2):

This function will do what you want.
Note that it changes the object by reference.
Note it ignores the first name as it's the object itself.

```
function setValue(location, value, object)
{
    var path = location.split(".");
    var current = object;
    for (var i = 1; i < path.length; i++)
    {
        if ((i + 1) == path.length)
            current[path[i]] = value;
        else
        {
            current[path[i]] = {};
            current = current[path[i]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want it to support strings where you can use the [ and ] syntax too? Any suggestion? Like this "myObject.test[value]" or "myObject.test['field1']". To support [value], maybe we could send another param to the function with all params in an array? Like setValue("myObject.test[value]", "myValue", myObject, {"value": "another value"});

Comment: @tidelipop `"myObject.test['value']"` is the same as `"myObject.test." + value` unless you have some wicked stuff in there like spaces ...

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObject = {};
var location = "test.my.deep.hidden.nested.myVar";
var otherLoc = "test.my.deep.secret.var";
var value = "My value!";

function setValue(location, value, obj){
  var i, prev = obj, curr;
  location = location.split(".");
  for(i = 0; i < location.length - 1; ++i){
    curr = prev[location[i]];
    if("object" !== typeof curr){
      prev[location[i]] = {}
      curr = prev[location[i]];
    }
    prev = curr;
  }
  curr[location[i]] = value;
}

setValue(location, value, myObject);
setValue(otherLoc, 42, myObject);

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

Result:

```
{
  "test": {
    "my": {
      "deep": {
        "hidden": {
          "nested": {
            "myVar": "My value!"
          }
        },
        "secret": {
          "var":42
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you might want to add some features, like checking whether the location is actually valid (`"this.is..invalid"`).

Answer (score -1):

You can simply access object inside another object by Dot(.)

So in your case, you are specifying the expression in quotes. You can try this out

```
var location = myObject.test.myVar; //Without quotes
```

and similarly if you have more nested objects.

Comment: Not if `myObject.test` doesn't exist.